# How I can use CSS active property in below code, It's not working fine

Tags: css, angular

When I'm on current (active) page the breadcrumb colour should be "Grey". After going on next page the previous breadcrumbs colour should be changed to "Blue".

```
.home-link-breadcrum .upper:active {
  display: block !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  color: grey !important;
}

.home-link-breadcrum .upper {
   color: blue !important;
}

.home-link-breadcrum .upper:hover {
  color: yellow !important;
}
```

Img 1 said that "Main category level 2 and Level 2 should be grey" because this is a Current (active) page and "Open new case Software licensing should be blue"
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The :active property is used when you have already clicked on a link/button : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

If you want to show your current position in the breadcrums you should use a class *.active* for the last element instead of a pseudo-class. Pseudo class are for when actions are taken on said element.

A breadcrumb is itself quite self-sufficient so that you should not have to mark links in a specific way

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a class since ':active' only works in the moment you click on the link.

```css
a:active {
  color: yellow;
}

a.active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">:active</a><a class="active" href="#">.active</a>
```